# How to check in the Angular2 (input) handler if the value is really changed

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel, event-binding

I want to run some code in an Angular2 component if the `ngModel` of an input field has changed. 
I want to listen on the `(input)` event because it's fired on any type of user interaction. This means that I can't use the `(change)` event here.
I want to run my code only if the value has changed.

Here is an example component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'myCuteComponent',
    templateUrl: `
        <h1>yoO World</h1>
        <input [(ngModel)]="cuteValue" (input)="onInput($event)">
    `
})
export class MyCuteComponent {

    cuteValue = '';

    constructor() { }

    onInput(event) {
        if (event.target.value !== this.cuteValue) {
            console.log('value has changed'); // this will never run :(
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `event.target.value` contains the new value already when `onInput` is fired. So this way won't work, the `console.log will` never run.

**Question:** Is there a proper (and general) solution to detect if value has really changed after any type of user interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'myCuteComponent',
    templateUrl: `
        <h1>yoO World</h1>
        <input [(ngModel)]="cuteValue" (ngModelChange)="onInput($event)">
    ` }) export class MyCuteComponent {

    onInput(value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

ControlValueAccessors will write the initial value with square brackets, and emit values changes with banana brackets. So [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) is shortened to [(ngModel)] to bind and emit on changes.

Comment: @Youdacheese Dude , do you mean parentheses ?

Comment: @xe4me yes you're correct, didn't go for the scientific term because it was missing from my brain that sad afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using OnChanges (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html)?

Something like:

```
import { Component, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'myCuteComponent',
    templateUrl: `
        <h1>yoO World</h1>
        <input [(ngModel)]="cuteValue" (input)="onInput($event)">
    `
})
export class MyCuteComponent implements OnChanges {

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    }
}
```